the difference between Appserver and Web.Host in nswag
I have 2 functions .
one is in the AppServer , like
[HttpPost]
functionA(ObnectDto dto)...
one is in the web.host ,likes
[HttpPost]
functionB(ObnectDto dto)...
the 2 functions all have the attribute of [HttpPost]
When i use the nswag to make the service-proxies.ts
and the 2 functions has differece result
functionA is
functionA(body?: dto | undefined): Observable {
functtonB is
functtonB(string?: itema | undefined, string?: itemb | undefined, tring?: itemc | undefined  ): Observable {
why the results are difference?
who can help me
i want to get the nswag  result like functionA
